# Android Recyclerview render error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, render

`Recyclerview` render error, this error prevents to preview whole layout so I am not able to see what changes I apply. I looked for the solution but nothing related this error helped.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.getDisplay(Landroid/view/View;)Landroid/view/Display;
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.java:2502)
>     at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:15395)  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2953)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2960)
>     at
>   android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:333)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:567)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:549)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:863)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:549)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$1(RenderTask.java:680)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Which version using (Recyclerview )??

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'

Comment: compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

Comment: minSdkVersion 16
       targetSdkVersion 25

Comment: Switch to `-v7:26.0.1`

Comment: Thanks so much, now I am able to see preview, but IDE started to give 'The following classes could not be instantiated recyclerview, textview button etc.. I invalidated chaches restarted IDE but the errors insists.

Comment: If you are using ItemDecoration for RecyclerView, try to remove it. In some cases(very rare), ItemDecoration may cause this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add this lines in `gradle` and `sync`.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.getDisplay(Landroid/view/View;)Landroid/view/Display;
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.java:2502)
>   at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:15395)

**CHANGE**

```
 android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'

  defaultConfig {
    targetSdkVersion 26
  }

compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-26.0.1'
```

After that **`Clean-Rebuild-Restart`** & Select **API Level 26** from Preview Section .

Comment: I had already done that settings but it still gives the warnings

Comment: @IlyasDirin `The following classes could not be instantiated recyclerview` another issue .I hope you overcome `NoSuchMethodError` problem

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error.
Try to remove your `android:animateLayoutChanges` in your RecyclerView.

Good luck